# Randomly generating a value not in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, random

I'm trying to generate session ids in Node and store them in MongoDB. For my application I only want to generate a random 6 digit number (this number is used to sync two sessions so it's short for users to easily copy). I want to generate a number that is not already in my `sessions` collection in MongoDB. My first thought which will probably work 99% of the time is this:

```
function GetSessionKey(cb) {
    var key = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000).toString();
    while (key.length < 6) key = '0' + key;
    db.sessions.find({ Key: key }, function (err, docs) {
        if (!err && docs.length == 0) {
            cb(key);
        } else {
            GetSessionKey(cb);
        }
    });
}
```

But there is a slim chance that the generated key constantly picks existing keys in mongo. Or the possibility that all keys are already in use (which I do not expect to happen).

I know Node is asynchronous but does that mean that a recursive async call like this will fill up the stack if it keeps getting called? Or do async calls not get put on the stack? Is there a better way to generate short unique keys? Old keys will be removed and can be reused so I don't think it's be a ticking time bomb. I'm just worried that the random aspect may cause trouble.

Comment: In order to reduce chance key conflicts with existing keys, I would suggest using base64 key format (of course under assumption that your key requirements allow other characters than digits). You could use `crypto` Node.js module e.g.  `crypto.randomBytes(6).toString('base64').slice(0, 6).replace(/\//g, '-').replace(/\+/g, '_')`. In the given example you can easily change number of characters if needed.

Comment: I don't know how to find random number NOT in collection. But your code will not fill up the stack because async use a queue instead of a stack. 6 digits for sessionid is dangerous, someone may fake another person on your website?

Comment: @damphat These numbers are used to pair android devices similarly to how bluetooth does it. And these sessions are much shorter lived.

Comment: @Tom base64 is not outside of my requirements. I may use it. The idea is that key length is short. Increasing the base can keep it short and increase possible values. I like it.

Comment: I'd generate each 'digit' independently (rather than as one giant number). It makes generating a digit/character for each position simple. Also, I'd suggest you batch create these as needed, rather than one at a time. You could then randomize the list order if they had been sequentially built).  I definitely wouldn't use a random number with an infinite search cycle for a production system.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use MongoDB to enforce uniqueness. For example, create an unique index on the `Key` field in the Mongo shell:

```
db.sessions.ensureIndex( { Key: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Modify the Node.js code to insert the generated random value and test the `err` variable for duplicate key errors. If there is no error, you're good to go. Otherwise, regenerate the value and try again. You can test for duplicate key errors like this:

```
...
db.sessions.insert({ Key: key }, function (err, docs) {
  ...
  if (err) {
    if (err.code && err.code == 11000) {
      // Duplicate key error. Generate a new random value and insert again.
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  ...
```

If you can store the generated key in the `_id` field instead of `Key`, then you can skip `ensureIndex(...)` as MongoDB automatically creates an unique index on `_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive async call will not fill up stack. They'll just spin cpu over and over again until they find a key or some kind of an error happens.

I suggest to set a reasonable maximum on an amount of guesses though. And yes, base64 (as suggested above) or base36 (that's simply .toString(36)) will increase amount of keys available reducing collision chance if you're worrying about that.

Edit: there is indeed a better way - sequential keys.

Comment: Sequential isn't very thread safe, or at least it over complicates things to make them thread safe. Instead I'd rather use random because I feel like I'll probably only be using 10% of the available keys at one time before they expire and can be reused.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn - thread safe? There would only be one thread executing the code at one time.